# What are the differences between TabbedPage navigation and Shell tabs navigation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

What are the differences between a navigation based on [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) and one based on [Shell Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs) (`Shell` + `TabBar` + `Tab`) ? (with examples if possible).

Is `Shell` a replacement of older [page navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms Shell is basically a container that was developed in order to improve the navigation complexity of Xamarin.Forms applications.
According to the Xamarin.Forms Shell documentation it provides the following advantages:

- Reduces the complexity of mobile application development
- Provides a common browsing user experience
- Uses a URI-based navigation scheme
- Has an integrated search controller

To start building your UI in shell this would be the starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ShellNavigationSample.Views"
      x:Class="ShellNavigationSample.AppShell">

</Shell>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you have only reported what was in the documentation, I am looking for concrete examples showing the differences (Example on how it reduces complexity...etc) with a more focus on TabbedPage vs Shell Tabs.

Comment: it reduces complexity by defining the nav structure in a single place instead of embedding it in multiple individual pages

Comment: When using Shell, navigation stack is always at the root. Meanwhile using tabbed page, it is not like that.